# compare variables from different functions

Tags: javascript

I have two JSON files that I need to compare two values from to see if they are equal but I am not sure how to compare the variables outside of the functions. Each variable produces a digit and I just need to check to see if they are equal

```
function UserInfo(UserInfoJson){
details = JSON.parse(UserInfoJson);
 var user = details.id;
}

function ClassInfo(ClassInfoJson){
details = JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson);
var teacher = details.teacherId;
}

if (user == teacher) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Return the variables from your functions, then invoke them and compare their returned values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
function UserInfo (UserInfoJson){
  return JSON.parse(UserInfoJson).id;
}

function ClassInfo (ClassInfoJson){
  return JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson).teacherId;
}

if (UserInfo(data) == ClassInfo(data)) {

}
```

Or:

```
function UserInfo (UserInfoJson){
  return JSON.parse(UserInfoJson);
}

function ClassInfo (ClassInfoJson){
  return JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson);
}

var userInfo  = UserInfo(userData),
    classInfo = ClassInfo(classData);

if (userInfo.id == classInfo.teacherId) {

}
```

If we're as far as we are, just simplify it to:

```
var userInfo  = JSON.parse(userData),
    classInfo = JSON.parse(classData);

if (userInfo.id == classInfo.teacherId) {

}
```

Comment: it will always parse json for getting id of user and teacher.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed This is just a concept to avoid globals.

Comment: but where is data or classData being defined?

Comment: @user3633334 Those are your `ClassInfoJson` and `UserInfoJson`

Comment: @hsz but these are just showing as "userData is not defined"

Comment: @user3633334 oh my.. just replace `userData` with proper variable with your data, so `UserInfoJson`

Answer (score 0):

add global definition at the start:

```
var user;
var teacher; 

function UserInfo (UserInfoJson){     
    details = JSON.parse(UserInfoJson);
    user = details.id;
}


function ClassInfo (ClassInfoJson){         
    details = JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson);
    teacher = details.teacherId;
}


if (user == teacher) {
// do something
}
```

you can now access and manipulate these variables in & out of functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = "";
function UserInfo (UserInfoJson){     
details = JSON.parse(UserInfoJson);
 user = details.id;
}

var teacher ="";
function ClassInfo (ClassInfoJson){         
details = JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson);
 teacher = details.teacherId;
}


if (user == teacher) {
// do something
}
```

Declare the variables before the functions

Answer (score 0):

initialize in scope where it is accessible outside of function:

```
var user,teacher;
function UserInfo (UserInfoJson){     
details = JSON.parse(UserInfoJson);
 user = details.id;
}


function ClassInfo (ClassInfoJson){         
details = JSON.parse(ClassInfoJson);
teacher = details.teacherId;
}


if (user == teacher) {
// do something
}
```